# Union 1 column and select additional

Tags: mysql, sql, union, aggregate-functions

I have two tables, one called "pinned" and one called "unread"

"pinned" looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+
|pinned_by|post_id|
+---------+-------+
|2        |3      |
+---------+-------+
|2        |5      |
+---------+-------+
```

"unread" looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+
|unread_by|post_id|
+---------+-------+
|2        |5      |
+---------+-------+
|2        |10     |
+---------+-------+
```

I want to select this from the two tables:

```
+-------+------+------+
|post_id|unread|pinned|
+-------+------+------+
|3      |0     |1     |
+-------+------+------+
|5      |1     |1     |
+-------+------+------+
|10     |1     |0     |
+-------+------+------+
```

How can I do this?  The values that come through for pinned and unread could be 1/0, 1/null, true/false, etc.  I don't really care as long as I could differentiate which post_id's came from unread, which came pinned, and which came from both.  I'm using MySQL.  The _by columns all have 2 in this example, but will vary in the actual implementation.  The thought is that a where unread_by=2 and where pinned_by=2 will be included somehow.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a POSTS table for a single list of post_id values?

Comment: yes, I should have included that sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that there is a table of Posts, you can do:

```
Select P.post_Id
    , Max( Case When UR.unread_by Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End ) As unread
    , Max( Case When P2.pinned_by Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End ) As pinned
From Posts As P
    Left Join Unread As UR
        On UR.post_Id = P.post_Id
    Left Join Pinned As P2
        On P2.post_id = P.post_id
Group By P.post_id
```

Comment: Very elegant...I switched your Max() to a Least(1,UR.unread_by) to return 1 or null, but the difference is probably negligible.  I'm going with this because I think it'll be faster then The Scrum Meister's approach with subqueries, but everyone feel free to chime in if that's a bad assessment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT post_id, SUM(PinCount), SUM(UnreadCount)
FROM (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) PinCount, 0 UnreadCount
    FROM pinned
    GROUP BY post_id
    UNION ALL SELECT post_id, 0, COUNT(*) UnreadCount
    FROM unread
    GROUP BY post_id
)
GROUP BY post_id
```

Or, if you have a `post` table which holds all the posts, you can use that table - since MySql doesn't have a full outer join.

```
SELECT t.post_id, p.PinCount, u.UnreadCount
FROM posts t LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) PinCount
    FROM pinned
    GROUP BY post_id
  ) p USING(post_id)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) UnreadCount
    FROM unread
    GROUP BY post_id
  ) u USING(post_id)
GROUP BY t.post_id
```

Comment: For your second example, there's an extra ")" before the last line.  Also, if posts.post_id is a primary key, and in the other two tables both columns are in the primary key, do I need that last GROUP BY?

Comment: @colin Fixed. Yes you can omit the final `GROUP BY` if it is a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(pinned.post_id,unread_post_id) AS postid, unread_by, pinned_by 
FROM pinned OUTER JOIN unread ON pinned.post_id = unread.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
   SELECT x.post_id,
          COUNT(u.unread_by) AS unread,
          COUNT(x.pinned_by) AS pinned
     FROM (SELECT p.post_id
             FROM PINNED p
           UNION
           SELECT u.post_id
             FROM UNREAD u) x
LEFT JOIN UNREAD u ON u.post_id = x.post_id
LEFT JOIN PINNED p ON p.post_id = x.post_id
 GROUP BY x.post_id
```